# Delphi's Android Installer Combined with Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I have Delphi 10.3 CE, setup for only Windows development. I'd like to now set it up for Android development. I would, however, also like to add Android Studio (Flutter) to the same machine. Assuming I'd like the installations to go as easily and smoothly as possible, does it matter the order in which I do these installs? (Things I'm thinking about: Will accept-the-default installations leave me with two separate copies of the Android SDK? Might the first install set a PATH variable that's overwritten by the second install, causing problems? Do Delphi and Android Studio use different version of the Java Development Kit?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Default Delphi 10.3 installs Android SDK inside Public Documents folder of your computer. This means that by Default Delphi will not use the sam SDK as Android Studio.

But if you wish you can change path to Android SDK inside Delphi Options and even use Multiple SDK versions at the same time.

[image: SDK Manager]